# Refresh flow without rebooting node server

Tags: total.js

I'm working with Total.js Flow. I would like to know if is possible to refresh my flow if I edit designer.json without rebooting my node server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I made some minor grammar edits to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible. But I'll add something like `FLOW.reload()` might this week :-). But you will need to add some `scheduler` or `watcher` for watching of `designer.json` file because `FLOW.reload()` will perform only reloading of Flow.

**UPDATE**: new version of Total.js Flow `v6` supports hot reloading of `designer.json` file. It can be reloaded by executing `FLOW.reload()` method for example in `code` component or directly in application.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for answering :), I just have another question, I would like to know where the insertion of the json on `designer.json` is made? Thank you :)

Comment: Here is the code: https://github.com/totaljs/flow/blob/master/source/index.js#L1642

Comment: Sorry for delay, I forgot to anwser. Now Flow supports `FLOW.reload()` for hot reloading of `designer.json`. So you can test it here: https://github.com/totaljs/flow (it's beta version with great new features).

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry i'm late too, i would like to know i have to implement a watcher ? or Flow.reload() i'll detect the changes alone ? thx

Comment: Hi, yes Flow emits `ON('flow.reload', function() {})` event. You can catch it.

Comment: Hi how can i refresh my Components ?